# How to grant permissions to Network Service to write in a remote location

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

I need to grant permissions to the Network Service account to write on a different machine on the same network. Can you tell me which permissions I should add?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx

> Services that run as the Network Service account access network resources by using the credentials of the computer account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grant rights to the remote resources to the computer account; this will allow for `NETWORK SERVICE` to access the resources.

Note that for this to work, the systems must be in a domain.

When granting permissions, Computer accounts aren't searched by default.  You'll need to change your search scope in the permission granting dialog:

[image: permissions]

Then select the computer that the `NETWORK SERVICE` is running as.

Comment: I've added a sentence from msdn that I might be misunderstanding. Doesn't it say that network resource access is possible?

Comment: @Timmy You're absolutely right - I was thinking that was just `SYSTEM`, I was mistaken.  Answer edited.

Comment: The "Computers" options is not there. How can I add it? Thanks!

Comment: @Timmy It's not under the object types button?  What is showing there?