# How can I grant a "Computer" user specifics permissions?

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

On the dialog "object types" I see:

- Built-in security principals
- Users
- Groups

But "Computers" is not there. How can I grant permissions for a computer user?

Comment: can you post a screenshot? Perhaps you're looking at the wrong object types dialogue.

Comment: @Mark Henderson: This question is related to another question I did. Please check the screenshoot of the accepted answer. http://serverfault.com/questions/302223/how-to-grant-permissions-to-network-service-to-write-in-a-remote-location

Comment: I'm trying to change permissions for a folder

Comment: gotcha. That's the correct place to be looking.

Comment: Is this server on a domain?

Comment: @Mark Henderson: yes

Comment: @Mark Henderson: sorry for confusing you with a wrong answer and thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm doubtful that the server in question is joined to a domain for the reason that there are no "local" computer accounts, there are only "domain" computer accounts and that accounts for why the computer object type is not present. Can you verify that the server is in fact joined to a Windows domain? If so, what type of domain? Windows NT, 2000, 2003, or 2008?

Can you give us a screenshot verifying the domain membership of this particular server?

Comment: maybe I'm confused. How can I check if the computer is joined to a domain? In case it's not joined is not possible to add computers accounts?

Comment: 1. Bring up the System Properties, select the Computer Name tab, look at what is reads for Full computer name and either Workgroup or Domain. You might try posting a screen shot of that tab for us. 2. There are no "local" computer accounts so if the computer is not joined to a domain then you won't be able to grant permissions on the folders to any computer accounts, because they don't exist.

Comment: My fault, the computer is joined to a Workgroup but not to a domain. Then, computer accounts are not available :(

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. On a side note, computers aren't actually "joined" to a Workgroup. A workgroup is a loose "association" of computers in the sense that they appear together in Network Neighborhood (or My Network Places) but they share no central user database, authentication provider, etc.

Comment: thanks for your help!. Then, granting remote permissions to Network Service is out of my possibilities, right? Please see my previous question http://serverfault.com/questions/302223/how-to-grant-permissions-to-network-service-to-write-in-a-remote-location

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why does it need to use the Network Service account? Can you use a standard user account, created specifically for this purpose? If so, I can give you a few suggestions as to how to do it.

Comment: Network Service is the user used by all application pools (IIS) on a web server farm and I'd need to provide to this user write permissions on a media server. If this is not possible, I'll need to create a custom user and assign it to all app pools. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're on track then. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I see Built-in security principals, Service Accounts, Computers, Groups, Users.

Not that I have much clue what kind of object you are setting the security for, or on what OS.

I guess whatever item you are setting security on cannot have computer account security set on it?

**EDIT**

What happens if you do it from the command line? e.g.

```
cacls "c:\folder\wherever" /E /G "domainname\computername$:F"
```

Comment: Setting permissions for a folder, the OS is on the question tags...

Comment: Ah, and, so it is.

Comment: See edit for suggestion.